# $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{nz^{n}}{1-z^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{(1-z^{n})^{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Consider for $z \in \mathbb{C}$$$f(z)= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{nz^{n}}{1-z^{n}}$$ and $$g(z) =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{(1-z^{n})^{2}}$$

How to show that $f(z) = g(z)$ for $z \in D(0,1)$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that for $\lvert w\rvert < 1$ we have

$$\frac{1}{(1-w)^2} = \frac{d}{dw}\frac{1}{1-w} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot w^{k-1}.$$

Expanding $1/(1-z^n)^2$ that way in $g$ we obtain

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^{(k-1)n}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^{kn}.$$

Expanding $1/(1-z^n)$ into a geometric series in $f$, we obtain

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{mn}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty nz^{kn}.$$

It remains to argue why we can change the order of summation in either double series.

Comment: is the changing of the order of summation possible due to absolute convergence ?

Comment: Yes. In cases where you don't have absolute convergence, changing the order of summation is typically hard to justify, if it is allowed at all. So testing for absolute convergence is the first thing to do when you want to switch. If you find absolute convergence, happiness ensues.

Comment: I'm a little suspicious how you can make a substitution $w=z^n$. How can you take a derivative with respect to $z^n$? If we take derivative of $1/(1-z^n)$ with respect to $z$, shouldnr we get $\frac{-nz^{n-1}{(1-z^n)^2}$, which is more complicated (I know you didn't, but if you did).

Comment: And could you also explain why the absolute convergence happens? Certainly $n|z^l|= n$, whose series doesn't converge....